# Running electron as GUI for Python and Sharing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, electron

I am looking to use electron as my GUI for future python projects.
I would like to be able to input information to the GUI side  (electron) and then once i press a button the python application runs without it just opening the python shell.
For example a calculator program in python where it gets the two values from electron and multiplies them by each other(just an example)

If anyone could lead me into any documentation or examples on how to do this would be much appreciated

Comment: If you google "Electron with Python" there are tutorials that pop up...

Comment: They seem to run in a python shell. Is there a way of it running within electron?

Comment: electron is at its core a javascript runtime

Comment: No.  Python runs from the interpreter.  In order to run a Python script you would need to run it from a shell, Electron does not have Python integrated.